# What is the probability that one team is not represented in the five selected players?

Tags: probability

A total of five players is selected at random from four sporting teams. Each of the team consists of ten players numbered from $~1~$ to $~10~$
What is the probability that one team is not represented in the five selected players?

This is my working out to the question 
$$P = \frac{(^{10}C_1)^{3}\times ^{27}C_2}{^{40}C_5}  = \frac{375}{703} $$

However, it is wrong and here is my teacher's solution
$$P = \frac{(^{10}C_3)\times (^{10}C_1)^{2} \times 3\times 4 + (^{10}C_2)^{2} \times ^{10}C_1 \times 3\times 4}{^{40}C_5}  =  \frac{5375}{9139} $$

I noticed that my value is smaller than his but I couldn't find where I got wrong. I actually think that my teacher's answer is incorrect since regarding the numerator, there might be some cases in which he considered 3 players from a team and one from each of the other two overlapping the second case when he considered 2 players from the first team and two from the second team and 1 from the other team. 
However, I really don't know. Please help me to figure out which part in my solution (or his) is wrong.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Why do you think that there is an overlap between the two cases?

Comment: If you wish to know where you made a mistake, it helps to explain how you arrived at your answer.

Answer (score 2):

For example, if there're four teams A,B,C,D.
There're 4 different ways that one team is not present, such as team A is not present, or team B is not present.

So in your formuala: $(^{10}C_1)^{3}\times ^{27}C_2$

i) It doesn't count which team is not present. 
ii) $(^{10}C_1)^{3}$ means select one member from three teams. In the next step $^{27}C_2$ means selecting any two members from the three teams but some choices are counted multiple times.

For example if in the first step, Alice from Team A, Bob from Team B and Cindy from Team C are selected and in the next step, Adam and Anwar from Team A are selected so we reach a choice (Alice, Adam, Anwar, Bob, Cindy).

But if in the first step, Adam from Team A, Bob from Team B and Cindy from Team C are selected and in the next step, Alice and Anwar from Team A are selected, we could reach the same choice (Alice, Adam, Anwar, Bob, Cindy) too.

The teacher's solution should be right since to select 5 members frmo exact 3 team, either one team contributes 3 members or two teams both contribute 2 members.

The $3\times 4$ in $(10C3)×(10C1)2×3×4$ is used to determine which team contributes 3 members and which team is not present.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m_i$ be the event that we miss a player from team $i$.
We can apply the inclusion-exclusion formula to find the probability we miss some team:

$$P(m_1 \cup m_2 \cup m_3 \cup m_4 ) = \sum_{i=1}^4 P(m_i) - \sum_{(i,j)} P(m_i \cap m_j) + \\
+ \sum_{(i,j,k)} P(m_i \cap m_j \cap m_k) $$

where we sum over all distinct $k$-tuples of team numbers. We stop at $3$-tuples, as we cannot miss *all* the teams.

Now, $$P(m_i)= \frac{\binom{30}{5}}{\binom{40}{5}}$$ (we pick 5 players from only 40 possible ones: all players minus the $10$ from team $i$) and this holds for all $5$  teams. So (thanks to the symmetry) the first sum is $4\frac{\binom{30}{5}}{\binom{40}{5}}$

$$P(m_i \cap m_j) = \frac{\binom{20}{5}}{\binom{40}{5}}$$ (we omit 20 players) and this holds for $\binom{4}{2}=6$ many $2$-tuples of teams. So the second sum is $6\frac{\binom{20}{5}}{\binom{40}{5}}$

Similarly you miss three fixed teams we are left with a probability
of $$P(m_i \cap m_j \cap j)= \frac{\binom{10}{5}}{\binom{40}{5}}$$

We have $\binom{4}{3}=4$ many $3$-tuples of teams to omit. (Or just 4 teams to use exclusively). So the third and final sum
equals $4\frac{\binom{10}{5}}{\binom{40}{5}}$

Now take the alternating sum of those. [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4*binomial%2830%2C5%29%2Fbinomial%2840%2C5%29+-+6*binomial%2820%2C5%29%2Fbinomial%2840%2C5%29+%2B+4*binomial%2810%2C5%29%2Fbinomial%2840%2C5%29++) tells us it equals $$\frac{6639}{9139}$$ which is about $0.726$

So my answer disagrees with both of you, I'm afraid. As N.F. Taussig points out in the comments, this is due to a difference in interpretation of "one team is not represented". I assume that this means that *at least* one team is not represented, possibly more, while the teacher's solution assumes *exactly* one team is not represented. As the question is possibly a translated one, I will not venture into a discussion which interpretation is the correct one in this case.

Comment: Ambiguity is there in sentence "What is the probability that one team is not represented in the five selected players?" where one team could be explained as exact one team (The teacher's result) or at least one team (Henno's result).

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes, thx. I edited from a wrong idea of 5 teams and didn't change all numbers correctly. The WA link gives the right numbers and answer though.

Comment: A suggestion:  Judging by the answer provided by the author of the question, the author meant exactly one team is missing, so you may wish to state that your answer addresses the stated question, which has the more natural interpretation that at least one team is missing.